# What is the difference between "put on hold" and "closed"?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions, on-hold

I see a lot of questions that is "put on hold" or "closed". But I don't see their difference. Can you tell me what is the difference between them?

Here are my guesses:

- People can only close question with the reasons that appears when you click flag -> should be closed:

[image]

otherwise, put on hold.

- You can do some operations to a question when it is put on hold but you can't do them if it is closed.

Are they correct?

Comment: [Answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) TL;DR; they are the same thing.  It says 'on hold' for 5 days to make it clear that improving the question can allow it to be re-opened.  And while on hold it goes into the re-open queue if edited. After 5 days the question is 'closed'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In theory, [it's a gentler way](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) to inform someone that their question may not meet the standards of the site.

Since the word "closed" sounds absolute and final, many people would get put off of it, since they weren't aware of (or were disillusioned by) the reopening process, in which if a question were brought up to standards, it *could* get reopened.

### In practice, there's not all that much difference.

Questions that are put "on hold" become "closed" after about five days.

1 out of 10 questions were put on hold/closed in the last 30 days, and of those, on average 11% of them were reopened, not counting duplicates (which enjoy a higher-than-average reopen rate).

---

The intention is explained [on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/175248) as well as the blog post, in that we don't want an incomplete yet salvageable question to get an incomplete answer, nor do we want to make it seem like we're being snooty or stuck up in that one's question simply wasn't *good* enough for the site and should be locked away, never to seen again<sup>1</sup>.

So, this gives the OP a chance.  A seeming slim chance, but a chance nonetheless, to have their question reopened.  I believe to some extent that the rewording has worked, although there are a lot of questions which simply don't get reopened (and for the most part, that's a good thing).

<sup>1:  There *are* terrible questions about it, but there are nicer ways to break it to someone.</sup>